# WordPress kicks me out of admin panel after publishing a post or uploading an image

Tags: php, wordpress, logout

I configured a website based on WordPress. Every time i publish a post or upload an image i get logged out of admin panel and can not login again; I can login only if i close the window and then login with my username and password.

I did some research on the problem and a lot of people mentioned it is because of Site URL and Home URL being different, so i did make sure they are not (now they both have "https://" and "www"). Even i set "WP_HOME" and "WP_SITEURL" in wp-config.php file to be identical as well and checked the database table for these values.

Also i thought it may be a custom theme or a plugin issue so i deactivated all the plugins and changed back to default theme but it did not solve the problem. So i think it's not a theme or plugin issue.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Any cache plugin or clear the browser cache

Comment: No, there is no plugin related to cache. Also i deactivated all plugins and still didn't solve my problem.

Comment: If you remove additional globals from wp_config.php (WP_HOME & WP_SITE_URL), does it help?

Comment: No, it didn't. Actually i first used general settings in admin panel to change URLs but it didn't work. Then i tried global variables, also didn't work for me.